# Finding the link of last table list using xpath (python)

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-crawler

```
<div id="js-map-search-result-nav" class="lookup-result-guide" style="width: 630px;">
<ul class="c-pagination lookup-result-pagination">
    <li class="c-pagination__list">
      <a href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/57/" class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--prev js-pjax-anchor" rel="prev">«&nbsp;Prev</a>
    </li>
  <li class="c-pagination__list"><a class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--num js-pjax-anchor" href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/54/">54</a></li> <li class="c-pagination__list"><a class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--num js-pjax-anchor" href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/55/">55</a></li> <li class="c-pagination__list"><a class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--num js-pjax-anchor" href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/56/">56</a></li> <li class="c-pagination__list"><a class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--num js-pjax-anchor" href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/57/">57</a></li> <li class="c-pagination__list"><span class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--num is-selected">58</span></li> <li class="c-pagination__list"><a class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--num js-pjax-anchor" href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/59/">59</a></li> <li class="c-pagination__list"><a class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--num js-pjax-anchor" href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/60/">60</a></li>   
    <li class="c-pagination__list">
      <a href="/en/tokyo/rstLst/59/" class="c-pagination__target c-pagination__target--next js-pjax-anchor" rel="next">Next &nbsp;»</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

1141 – 1160 of 131715

I want to know how to get the xpath to get the link of last li tag no matter using response.css or response.xpath

This is the code that I am writing

for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="js-map-search-result-nav"]/ul/li[-1]/a/@href'):
    yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> (//ul[contains(@class,'lookup-result-pagination')]/li)[last()]
> ```

or

> `(//ul[contains(@class,'c-pagination')]/li)[last()]`

get last li element inside `//ul[contains(@class,'lookup-result-pagination')]`

and here is css locator:

> ul.c-pagination>li:last-child

but last li - is "Next" button in your case, do you need it, or last page number?

In that case you can use Xpath that checks that last li has no Next text

> (//ul[contains(@class,'c-pagination')]/li[not(./a[contains(text(),'Next')])])[last()]

Comment: Do you know how to use response.css to find the link of last li tag by using its class name?

Comment: heh sorry i missed to remove uneeded part with which i was debugging) try now)

Comment: also added css locator

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you tell me the problem of these code?  
    response.xpath('//*[@id="js-map-search-result-nav"]/ul/li[-1]/a/@href')

Comment: sure) that locator is totally incorrect) i'll explain: `li[-1‌​] ` - you try to get element that has position -1, which is imposible. To get last -1 element - use 
`(locator)[last()-1]`

Comment: Would you share some links about learning css locator? Since I have read through its official tutorial but still not fully understand it.

Comment: i used only this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp, and check locators using chrome dev tools